# Axios post request is not working in React Native

Tags: reactjs, api, react-native, axios

I'm getting my token from an API but unfortunately my API is returning 400 bad request. I've already checked my api via Postman and it's working fine there. Kindly let me know solution or any mistake.

```
async componentWillMount(){
 axios.post('http://api.myapiurl.com/token', {
                grant_type: 'PASSWORD',
                username: 'MY_USERNAME',
                password: 'MY_PASSWORD'
            }, {
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
                }
            }).then(response => {
                console.log(response.data)
            }).catch(err => console.log("api Erorr: ", err.message))
}
```

error in catch

> Request failed with status code 400

Comment: @iRohitBhatia Please check

Comment: Do you send the same headers in the postman like? Maybe you just need to send  like this: ` headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}`

Comment: I'm sending the same headers

Comment: Can you try to send the header in my comment?

Comment: `Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

Comment: I mean application/json

Comment: Not working @SuleymanSah

Comment: Can you change console.log like this in catch block? `console.log(errr.response)` and share what displays?

Comment: `error: unsupported_grant_type`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203667/discussion-between-suleymansah-and-zain-khan).

Comment: Just solved please check the answer

Comment: I told you to use 'password'

Comment: @Bored please check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solve by myself using `QueryString.stringify()`. I just pass the body into `QueryString.stringify()` like below:

```
axios.post('http://api.apiurl.com/token', QueryString.stringify({
            grant_type: 'MY_GRANT_TYPE',
            username: 'MY_USERNAME',
            password: 'MY_PASSWORD'
        }), {
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            }
        }).then(response => {
            console.log(response.data)
        }).catch(err => console.log("api Erorr: ", err.response))
```

Comment: Explain what's the problem and QueryString.stringify() what's do

Comment: Problem is already explained in question and the `querystring` module provides utilities for parsing and formatting URL query strings