# React Native Axios HTTPS connection

Tags: react-native, ssl, https, axios

I'm new in React native developpement, i'm working on an app for packages inventory with Front-End React native and Backend-end DOT NET Core API.
I use Axios to call the APIs, my backend is set up to run with HTTPS on an IIS server.
when i test in local every thing works perfectly but when i test with the Back-End published the Axios return [Network Error].
i suspect the problem is from the HTTPS protocol but i'm n ot sure.
this is my Axis call:

```
axios.post(`https://company-soft.com/api/login`, 
{
username:username,
password:password
})
.then((e)=>
{
console.log(e.data);
})
.catch((err)=>
{
 console.log(`login error: ${e}`);
});
```

PS:i tested the API with Postman and it is responding fine.
i already tried some codes to override the SSL verifivation like the httpsAgent but i'v been told that it dosen't work with react Native.
is there a way to do it with Ract Native and Axios ??
Thanks a lot.

Comment: [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59194579/axios-post-request-is-not-working-in-react-native)

Comment: @Ahmed5G my problem is not in the data format since the axios call works fine in localhost test, the problem occurs when i test with the published backend in IIS.

Comment: I tried to hit your domain "https://company-soft.com/" it says site can't be reached, please check hosted url, there is some issue.

Comment: @AlokSingh that is not my company domain, it is a fake one, i'm not permitted to give the real one, but i assure you the domain is responding fine.